# Can anyone help to pickup a unit test frame work that best suits my scenario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have just been assigned a task to implement a unit testing strategy for a small development team using c sharp on visual studio 2012 professional edition (which doesn't include the powerful full version of MS testing module (test manager, test center, ability to generate unit tests automatically, etc)).

After searching from the web and read a lot of articles about unit testing in visual studio, I have come up with a few options such as "nUnit", "xUnit.net" and the integrated MS unitTest coming with Visual Studio 2012 professional.(Because its only professional version, I just fund the function is very limited).
Can anybody with experience in this field help me to select a right tool? If you have any other suggestions please specify.

Also, we need to pick up a "fake" framework for creating "stub" and "drivers" for module testing as well. Since we still only have the VS 2012 professional version, we don't have access to the "MS fakes". I know "Moq" could be a good solution.
I would love anybody could suggest any better option.

Thanks

Comment: "What is you favorite..." is not very good question for SO... "I tried XXXX and it missing YYYYY feature, would ZZZZ provide it (or XXXX actually have it)?" may be better way to phrase such question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also recommend [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) as a great starting point for your unit testing, because it is free, it has integration into Visual Studio (if you wish, but also can run standalone as well) and also can complement other testing frameworks (like MSTest) if you decide to use/buy later. In other words, you could have tests written using NUnit and MSTest coexisting.

Read [A Step-by-Step Beginner Tutorial on Writing Unit Tests NUnit with C#](http://hippieitgeek.blogspot.com/2013/02/a-beginner-tutorial-on-writing-unit.html).

As for mocking, I recommend the following:

- [Moq](https://github.com/Moq) - free and regularly updated on GitHub
- [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) - free and regularly updated on website
- [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) - not free, but extremely powerful mocking framework that allows you to mock concrete types (including sealed classes) which allows you to test third party software, such as SharePoint, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use `nUnit` And it's great.

- It can be integrated with VS 2012 using the [nUnit test adapter extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d).
- It can be used as a [stand alone](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=installation&r=2.4)
- [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) CI server supports it (don't know about others...).
- It is used very widely and you could find [tutorials](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.2.10) and example for practically everything you need.

You can also "[Mock](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10719/Introducing-Rhino-Mocks)" objects, if this is what you mean by: "`"fake" framework for creating "stub" and "drivers"`"

Comment: Thanks. How about the mocking library? Any idea?

Comment: @HappyProgrammer What about it? do you mean how to use it?

Comment: Sorry, when I added the comment I haven't seen the part you mentioned "Mock" objects. Thanks for you answer. But what is the specific reason that you use nUnit against MSTest? And how do you usually organize your testing files (test harness)? By putting them under the same solution folder or organized them separately somewhere else? Thanks